# Splitting a string twice in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to break up this raw string into new lines, where UPDATE (of every #1234 should be in a new line along with every #1234 in new line aswell, it can be better understood as an example :

`` #1234 23:28:13 sesedsr id 235768 end_log_pos 4347687 CRC32 0xfe136bd2 Query thread_id=1425356 exec_time=0 error_code=0 UPDATE sys_stat SET `sys_updated_by` = 'system', `sys_mod_count` = 19014, `sys_updated_on` = '2019-04-30 06:28:13', `type` = 'warning', `value` = ' running: xyzz' WHERE sys_status.`sys_id` = '2c5d43134f0262cf5210c712' /* nsdkjsnda1, gs:glide.scheduler.worker.0, tx:649346ba4f052cf5210c774 */--#1234 23:28:13 sedsdr id 608695768 end_log_pos 4350401 CRC32 0xcf3a7672 Query thread_id=1425363 exec_time=0 error_code=0 UPDATE sys_trig SET `sys_updated_by` = 'system', `sys_mod_count` = 4263170, `state` = 1, `sys_updated_on` = '2019-04-30 06:28:13' WHERE sys_trigger.`sys_id` = '64a31111f933130017c49d4d19eedeb6' /* ndaassdasdev02_1, gs:glide.scheduler.worker.0, tx:649346ba0899d62cf5210c774 */--#1234 23:28:13 ssder id 608695768 end_log_pos 4357673 CRC32 0x80dd6e55 Query thread_id=1425359 exec_time=0 error_code=0 UPDATE syseve SET `state` = 'resumed.2c9346ba4f9d62cf5210c774', `claimed_by` = 'appdsa32.sedassd.abcd.com:nas1' WHERE (sysevent0004.`process_on` <= '2019-04-30 06:28:13' AND sysevent0004.`state` = 'encore-ready' AND sysevent0004.`queue` = 'flow_engine') /* nsfsdfs1, gs:glide.scheduler.worker.0, tx:649346ba4f05f740899d62cf5210c774 */--#1234 23:28:13 ssader id 608695768 end_log_pos 4358824 CRC32 0xf281abf6 Query thread_id=1425365 exec_time=0 error_code=0 UPDATE syseve SET `state` = 'queued.2c9346ba4f05f740899d62cf5210c774', `claimed_by` = 'apdasda121.sesadasd.sbcd-ffd.com:ndasdasv02_1' WHERE (sysevent0004.`process_on` <= '2019-04-30 06:28:13' AND sysevent0004.`state` = 'ready' AND sysevent0004.`queue` = 'flow_engine') /* nsdfs2_1, gs:glide.scheduler.worker.0, tx:649346ba4f05f5210c774 */--UPDATE sys_trigger SET `log` = 0, `trigger_type` = 1, `sys_mod_count` = 4263171, `sys_updated_on` = '2019-04-30 06:28:13', `error_count` = 0, `priority` = 100, `trigger_class` = 'com.snc.process_flow.engine.PFJob', `job_context` = '#Mon Apr 29 23:28:13 PDT 2019 ', `run_count` = 1421121, `sys_id` = '64a31111f93313edeb6', `sys_updated_by` = 'system', `sys_created_on` = '2018-08-07 11:38:16', `job_id` = '88d87a408f3222037bdeeb5', `repeat` = '1970-01-01 00:00:16', `processing_duration` = 58, `name` = 'Flow Engine Event Handler', `next_action` = '2019-04-30 06:28:24', `state` = 0, `maintenance` = 0, `sys_created_by` = 'guest', `upgrade_safe` = 1, `claimed_by`= NULL WHERE sys_trigger.`sys_id` = '64a349d4d19eedeb6' /* nsadsfd02_1, gs:glide.scheduler.worker.0, tx:649346ba9d62cf5210c774 */ ``

### To look like :

```
#1234 23:28:13 sdasver id 235768 end_log_pos 4347687 CRC32 0xfe136bd2 Query thread_id=1425356 exec_time=0 error_code=0 

UPDATE sys_stat SET `sys_updated_by` = 'system', `sys_mod_count` = 19014, `sys_updated_on` = '2019-04-30 06:28:13', `type` = 'warning', `value` = ' running: xyzz' WHERE sys_status.`sys_id` = '2c5d43134f0262cf5210c712' /* nsdkjsnda1, gs:glide.scheduler.worker.0, tx:649346ba4f052cf5210c774 */

#1234 23:28:13 sasdar id 608695768 end_log_pos 4350401 CRC32 0xcf3a7672 Query thread_id=1425363 exec_time=0 error_code=0 

UPDATE sys_trig SET `sys_updated_by` = 'system', `sys_mod_count` = 4263170, `state` = 1, `sys_updated_on` = '2019-04-30 06:28:13' WHERE sys_trigger.`sys_id` = '64a31111f93319d4d19eedeb6' /* nasdada02_1, gs:glide.scheduler.workr.0, tx:649346ba0f5210c774 */

#1234 23:28:13 sdaser id 608695768 end_log_pos 4357673 CRC32 0x80dd6e55 Query thread_id=1425359 exec_time=0 error_code=0 

UPDATE syseve SET `state` = 'resumed.2c9346ba4f9d62cf5210c774', `claimed_by` = 'apd032.sasds0.dsadasce-sdas.com:nas1' WHERE (sysevent0004.`process_on` <= '2019-04-30 06:28:13' AND sysevent0004.`state` = 'encore-ready' AND sysevent0004.`queue` = 'flow_engine') /* nsfsdfs1, gs:glide.scheduler.workr.0, tx:649346ba4f05f745210c774 */

#1234 23:28:13 sdaser id 608695768 end_log_pos 4358824 CRC32 0xf281abf6 Query thread_id=1425365 exec_time=0 error_code=0 

UPDATE syseve SET `state` = 'queued.2c9346ba4f05f740899d62cf5210c774', `claimed_by` = 'apsds0asd32.sedasd0.dce-nasdaow.csdsdm:ndasdav02_1' WHERE (sysevent0004.`process_on` <= '2019-04-30 06:28:13' AND sysevent0004.`state` = 'ready' AND sysevent0004.`queue` = 'flow_engine') /* nsdfs2_1, gs:glide.scheduler.workr.0, tx:649346ba4f05f5210c774 */

UPDATE sys_trigger SET `log` = 0, `trigger_type` = 1, `sys_mod_count` = 4263171, `sys_updated_on` = '2019-04-30 06:28:13', `error_count` = 0, `priority` = 100, `trigger_class` = 'com.snc.process_flow.engine.PFJob', `job_context` = '#Mon Apr 29 23:28:13 PDT 2019 ', `run_count` = 1421121, `sys_id` = '64a31111f93313edeb6', `sys_updated_by` = 'system', `sys_created_on` = '2018-08-07 11:38:16', `job_id` = '88d87a408f3222037bdeeb5', `repeat` = '1970-01-01 00:00:16', `processing_duration` = 58, `name` = 'Flow Engine Event Handler', `next_action` = '2019-04-30 06:28:24', `state` = 0, `maintenance` = 0, `sys_created_by` = 'guest', `upgrade_safe` = 1, `claimed_by`= NULL WHERE sys_trigger.`sys_id` = '64a349d4d19eedeb6' /* nsadsfd02_1, gs:glide.scheduler.workr.0, tx:6493asdd62cf5210c774 */
```

I have already split the raw string once by ("--") and have broken it into a separate line.
Also: #1234 -> can be dynamic (#abcd)

Comment: do you have some linefeed in the string? or other markers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on `#1234` or `UPDATE` using lookahead and alternation

```
(?=#1234)|(?=UPDATE)
```

```js
let str = "#1234 23:28:13 server id 235768 end_log_pos 4347687 CRC32 0xfe136bd2 Query thread_id=1425356 exec_time=0 error_code=0 UPDATE sys_stat SET `sys_updated_by` = 'system', `sys_mod_count` = 19014, `sys_updated_on` = '2019-04-30 06:28:13', `type` = 'warning', `value` = ' running: xyzz' WHERE sys_status.`sys_id` = '2c5d43134f0262cf5210c712' /* nsdkjsnda1, gs:glide.scheduler.worker.0, tx:649346ba4f052cf5210c774 */--#1234 23:28:13 server id 608695768 end_log_pos 4350401 CRC32 0xcf3a7672 Query thread_id=1425363 exec_time=0 error_code=0 UPDATE sys_trig SET `sys_updated_by` = 'system', `sys_mod_count` = 4263170, `state` = 1, `sys_updated_on` = '2019-04-30 06:28:13' WHERE sys_trigger.`sys_id` = '64a31111f933130017c49d4d19eedeb6' /* nsalabdev02_1, gs:glide.scheduler.worker.0, tx:649346ba0899d62cf5210c774 */--#1234 23:28:13 server id 608695768 end_log_pos 4357673 CRC32 0x80dd6e55 Query thread_id=1425359 exec_time=0 error_code=0 UPDATE syseve SET `state` = 'resumed.2c9346ba4f9d62cf5210c774', `claimed_by` = 'app128032.sea10.service-now.com:nas1' WHERE (sysevent0004.`process_on` <= '2019-04-30 06:28:13' AND sysevent0004.`state` = 'encore-ready' AND sysevent0004.`queue` = 'flow_engine') /* nsfsdfs1, gs:glide.scheduler.worker.0, tx:649346ba4f05f740899d62cf5210c774 */--#1234 23:28:13 server id 608695768 end_log_pos 4358824 CRC32 0xf281abf6 Query thread_id=1425365 exec_time=0 error_code=0 UPDATE syseve SET `state` = 'queued.2c9346ba4f05f740899d62cf5210c774', `claimed_by` = 'app128032.sea10.service-now.com:nsalabdev02_1' WHERE (sysevent0004.`process_on` <= '2019-04-30 06:28:13' AND sysevent0004.`state` = 'ready' AND sysevent0004.`queue` = 'flow_engine') /* nsdfs2_1, gs:glide.scheduler.worker.0, tx:649346ba4f05f5210c774 */--UPDATE sys_trigger SET `log` = 0, `trigger_type` = 1, `sys_mod_count` = 4263171, `sys_updated_on` = '2019-04-30 06:28:13', `error_count` = 0, `priority` = 100, `trigger_class` = 'com.snc.process_flow.engine.PFJob', `job_context` = '#Mon Apr 29 23:28:13 PDT 2019 ', `run_count` = 1421121, `sys_id` = '64a31111f93313edeb6', `sys_updated_by` = 'system', `sys_created_on` = '2018-08-07 11:38:16', `job_id` = '88d87a408f3222037bdeeb5', `repeat` = '1970-01-01 00:00:16', `processing_duration` = 58, `name` = 'Flow Engine Event Handler', `next_action` = '2019-04-30 06:28:24', `state` = 0, `maintenance` = 0, `sys_created_by` = 'guest', `upgrade_safe` = 1, `claimed_by`= NULL WHERE sys_trigger.`sys_id` = '64a349d4d19eedeb6' /* nsadsfd02_1, gs:glide.scheduler.worker.0, tx:649346ba9d62cf5210c774 */"

console.log(str.split(/(?=#1234)|(?=UPDATE)/).filter(Boolean))
```

Comment: NOTE: The `.filter(Boolean)` just removes values from a list which are "falsey",
like empty strings or null.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dataParsed = data
.replace(/UPDATE/g, '\n\nUPDATE') // replace every update with update and two new lines
.replace(/(\#[a-zA-Z0-9]{4})/g, '\n\n$1') // take group of four alphanumerics starting with # and replace with this group and new 2 new lines
```